# Why does sed fail when I am trying to extract part of a regex?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed, cygwin

I have a list of files in a directory that have the following naming convention:prefix_2chars_suffix
Example: `currentfile_aa_belongsToprojectForDep` `currentfile_bb_belongsToprojectForDep`  etc.
I wanted to "extract the 2 characters between the prefix and suffix. So I thought to use sed.
I tried the following:

```
ls currentfile_* | sed 's/currentfile_\([..]\)_belongsToprojectForDep/\1/g'
```

I get:

> sed: -e expression #1, char 44: unknown command: `\'

But when I do this:
`echo this is digit 7 in a number | sed 's/digit \([0-9]\)/\1/'`
It works, meaning I don't get an error about my syntax
What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to place them between `[]`:

```
ls currentfile_* | sed 's/currentfile_\(..\)_belongsToprojectForDep/\1/g'
```

Also you can just use cut:

```
ls currentfile_* | cut -f 2 -d _
```

A more accurate form as well is

```
ls currentfile_??_belongsToprojectForDep | cut -f 2 -d _
```

Comment: Removing the square brackets gives me the same error (char 42 now)

Comment: @Jim Can you see what version of sed you're using (Try `sed --version`)? Perhaps sed doesn't support the feature. Are you in bash or a shell as well? You can consider cut.

Comment: Also make sure that it's still quoted around `''`.

Comment: I am using sed 4.2.2 in cygwin. Your `cut` works (+1) but I want to do it in sed for learning

Comment: There should be not much difference even in cygwin. I'm not sure how it doesn't work but you can try other forms as well: `ls currentfile_??_belongsToprojectForDep | sed -r 's|^[^_]+_(..)_.*|\1|'`. If it does work perhaps it was a bug in sed, or perhaps some characters are different there somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing the output of *ls* is very bad practice. Moreover, *sed* is not really useful in your case (even though I read in a comment you want to learn *sed*, you'd better instead learn to use properly the proper tools in a given situation — and learn to *not* parse the output of *ls*). You can consider the following pure *bash* solution instead:

```
for i in currentfile_??_*; do
    [[ $i =~ ^[^_]+_([^_][^_])_[^_]+$ ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
done
```

This should be rather robust. Even more robust if you use it with `shopt -s nullglob`.

- We don't like to parse the output of *ls*. We use glob instead. Here the glob makes sure we only loop on filenames that have two underscores separated by two characters. We may have too many filenames here, as, e.g., a filename like `currentfile_a__cool_file_is_very_cool` or `currentfile____ilikeunderscores__` will match.
- Among the filenames found, we'll use a regex to filter further the ones we want, i.e., those that have exactly 2 underscores (hence separated by two non-underscore characters).
- The `${BASH_REMATCH[1]}` will expand to the first matching pattern (observe the parenthesis in the regexp).

The first point is the counterpart of your *ls*-pipe. The last two points are the counterpart of your *sed* statement.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I don't understand the `for` loop.How does it know to read from e.g. the current directory. I.e. that the `currentfile..` is a filename?

Comment: @Jim that's what the globs do: `*` expands to all files in current directory. Try it: `echo *` will echo all filenames in current directory. `echo *a*` will echo all filenames in current directory that contain an `a`, etc... In fact, you already used this feature when you did `ls currentfile_*`.

Comment: `We don't like to parse the output of ls` Why though?

Comment: @Jim [This link to Greg's wiki _ParsingLs_ page](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) should give you some nice information about the problems that will bite you in the back if you start parsing the output of _ls_.